# Writing a django migration manually with setting a variable on condition

Tags: python, django, data-migration, django-migrations

I need to write a django migration which changes an attribute value depending on a condition.

So I have `is_admin` and `is_staff` attributes, and now I am substituting the with the new attribute `role`.

I need to set `role = admin` if the old `is_admin` was true. 
Similarly, I need to set `role = staff` if the `old is_staff` was true.

How can I do that with django data migrations?

I need something like

```py
if is_admin:
    role = "admin"
if is_staff:
    role = "staff"
```

SOLUTION:
So I found the solution in RunPython

```py
def role_populator(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("core", "User")
    for inst in User.objects.all():
        if inst.is_superuser:
            inst.role = RoleField.superadmin
        elif inst.is_staff:
            inst.role = RoleField.manager
        else:
            if inst.agency:
                inst.role = RoleField.realtor
            else:
                inst.role = RoleField.individual


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [("core", "0017_auto_20190611_1008")]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(role_populator, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

for user in User.objects.all():
    if user.is_admin:
       role = 'admin'
```

Comment: Nope. I found the solution. Will add this to my question. Thanks though :)